# TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a React-app with Jest. I use Enzyme's shallow to render my `App.js` component in `App-test-js` but I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined`

This is my `App.js`:

```js
/* global google */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Geosuggest from 'react-geosuggest';
import { getAirQuality } from './Client'
import DataTable from './DataTable'
import Errors from 'react-errors'


class App extends Component {

  .
  .
  .

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.searchAirQuality.bind(this)}>
          <Geosuggest
            placeholder="Type a location and press SEARCH button!"
            onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect.bind(this)}
            initialValue={this.state.place}
            location={new google.maps.LatLng(53.558572, 9.9278215)}
            radius="20"/>
          <button className="my-button" type="submit" disabled={!this.state.place}>Button</button>
        </form>
        <DataTable items={this.state.items} />
        <Errors
          errors={this.state.errors}
          onErrorClose={this.handleErrorClose}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is my `App-test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from  'enzyme'
import App from '../components/App.js'

describe( '<App />', () => {
  it('Button disable when input is empty', () => {
    const App = shallow(<App />);

    expect(App.find('.my-button').hasClass('disabled')).to.equal(true);

  });

});
```

And this the error when I run `npm test`:

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkNwL.png)

This is my first time with testing in jest, please could someone help me with any idea about this error?

Comment: Can u trace out where the contextType is used,I couldnt find the contextType there in your snippet, All you need to do is to define the object which calls contextType.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem here is that you are redefining the the app component with the result of the shallow call

```js
//    Redefining
//    ↓
const App = shallow(<App />);
```

The solution would be to use a different name:

```js
//    Use a different name
//    ↓
const app = shallow(<App />);
```

Comment: Always good to use `const wrapper = shallow(<App />);` as the return of a `shallow()` is a shallow wrapper.

Answer (score 44):

This would be the same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined` when **you are importing something that does not exist**.

Here is an example:
`AccountFormComponent.jsx` (incorrect class name):

```
export class FoeFormComponent extends React.Component { .... }
```

`AccountFormComponent.test.jsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { expect, assert } from 'chai'
import { AccountFormComponent } from '../../src/components/AccountFormComponent';

describe('', function () {
  it('', function () {
    const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<AccountFormComponent {...props} />);
  });
});
```

Just add the following to your test file to be sure the component exists:

```
it('should exists', function () {
    assert.isDefined(AccountFormComponent);
});
```

which prints `AssertionError: expected undefined to not equal undefined` instead

Comment: This was the issue for me. I was accidentally importing via destructuring thinking the export was normal, rather than `export default`.

Had to change:
`import { MyComponent } from './index'`
to:
`import MyComponent from './index'`

Comment: this is the perfect answer, it's unfortunate that some syntax/linting tools can't catch this sort of error.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had the same problem as @Brendan, and was assuming `export default` + `import Name` instead of the actual `export const` + `import { Name }`.

Comment: As I was converting class components to functions with hooks, I forgot to export. I imagine lots of folks may make the same mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

In my case the error occurred when imported a module that has only one default export, but I was using single import.

So instead of:

```
import { Foo } from './Foo'
```

use:

```
import Foo from './Foo'
```

where Foo has default export:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
   return (<div>foo</div>)
  }
}
export default Foo;
```

Comment: The difference between both imports depends on if you are using the export default  or export on the component, thank you your answer works for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was importing a default component with named component syntax.

For example, something like:

```
import {TestComponent} from "../../components/TestComponent";
```

instead of

```
import TestComponent from "../../components/TestComponent";
```

Updating the import to use the right syntax fixed the issue.  Silly one though.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ser mentioned could be a import issue.
If you are using eslint rules this could give you a hint if any of the imports might fail

```
"import/no-unresolved": 1,
```

I got that error on trying to import a component from a jsx file

```
import {Header} from './Header';
```

this fixed it

```
import {Header} from './Header.jsx';
```

Also because I used webpack I realised that I should have added '.jsx' to resolve.extensions option. This way I can ignore the extensions when importing.